# Какая область видимости у цикла for без фигурных скобок в java?

Tags: java, циклы

Здравствуйте коллеги!

Узнал сегодня, что синтаксис `java` допускает цикл `for` оставлять без фигурных скобок. Вот хотя бы подпрограмма сравнения строк:

```
  public static boolean compare (String a, String b){
      if(a.length()!= b.length())
          return false;
      for(int i = 0; i<a.length();i++)
          if(a.charAt(i)!=b.charAt(i))
               return false;
      return true;
  }
```

**Вопросы:** Верно ли, что область видимости у цикла for (без {}), будет одна логическая строчка?  Если так, получается ли что можно бесконечно много вложить циклов в соседнюю строчку и программа будет работать? (То есть допустим ли такой ступенчатый синтаксис):

```
for(int i = 0; i<2;i++)
 if(i>0)
  for(int j = 0; j<2;i++) //и так 5000 строк
```

**P.S.** Если у кого-нибудь есть ссылка на статью по вопросу, дайте пожалуйста.

Comment: на самом деле что есть скобки что нету - одинаковая область видимости. Вложить то можно, только мне кажется там опечатка, второй раз `i <2;i++`

Comment: Верно. Можно. Какая тут может быть статья, если это примитивные основы языка?

Comment: если смотреть [специфкацию](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1), то после инициализации должен идти [Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5) и на самом деле ничего про скобки нет.

Comment: @pavel поправил опечатку. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если использовать цикл `for` без фигурных скобок, то он будет выполнять только следующую команду.
Например, Вы предложили в одной и той же строке сделать написать несколько команд:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    System.out.print(1); System.out.print(2);
```

В этом случае, вывод будет такой: `11112`, и если требуется выполнять обе команды каждую итерацию цикла, то надо их заключить в фигурные скобки.

Насчет вложенных циклов - все верно, так действительно делать можно.

На будущее, в java-конвенции требуется, чтобы любое использование операторов `if`, `if-else`, а так же циклов `for`, `while` `do-while` были вместе с фигурными скобками. Исключение - если они пустые. [Вот тут это описано](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-142311.html#449)

Answer (score 2):

То что вы называете областью видимости скорее тело цикла, которое будет итеративно выполняться. Да, если явно скобками его не определить то тело будет сосоять из одного логического выражения, которое может быть вложенно так-же без явного указания тела, как в вашем примере. Это просто синтаксический сахар, такой прием работает и с условиями if,  например. А вот область видимости у циклов отсутствует, т.е. если вы определите переменную в теле цикла то она будет доступна далее по коду метода.

Comment: Последнее не верно. Вот это не скомпилируется: `for (int i = 0; i <5; i++) {
            int a=0;
        }

        System.out.println(a);` хоть со скобками хоть нет. Т.е. область видимости есть для всего, окружённого скобками, если это не поля класса с модификаторами доступа

Comment: Спасибо. Было интересно прочитать ваш ответ. Но другой парень ответил лучше.